# read_grib, where to put ibm2fltmex5.dll

Tags: matlab

I need to read some Meteological data in grib format. I have download a code which can read the data. but in the middel of code ibm2fltmex5.dll is needed. I have download the dll too from [ibm2fltmex5.dll](https://meteo.unican.es/trac/MLToolbox/browser/MLToolbox/MeteoLab/Read_GRIB/ibm2fltmex5.dll?rev=1). I have created folders (MeteoLab\Read_GRIB) in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox) and put the dll in it.I restart my PC but that code error again.

```
function bds_struct=get_bds(fid,lenbds)
bds=fread(fid,11);
bds_struct.len=lenbds;
bds_struct.oct4=bds(4);
bds_struct.bsfE=int2(bds(5),bds(6));
bds_struct.RefVal=ibm2fltmex5(bds(7:10));
bds_struct.nbits=bds(11);
bds=fread(fid,lenbds-11);
bds_struct.bindata=uint8(bds);
```

error is

> Undefined function or method 'ibm2fltmex5' for input arguments of type
>   'double'

.
Did I put dll in the correct place? what else should I do?
Any comments is appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another Way, there is a Matlab function which do the same: can be download from :
[ibm2flt.m](https://github.com/BrianOBlanton/read_grib/blob/master/private/ibm2flt.m)